# EmberJS I need help modifying attributes inside of the built in view Ember.Checkbox

Tags: ember.js

I have a property bound in my handlebar template

```
{{view Ember.Checkbox checkedBinding="state"}}
```

I would like the checked state of the checkbox to be the opposite of what the bound value is.  Can I do this with the view like that or do I need to use a computed property? I'm trying to avoid computed because the checkbox is on a table inside of an each with a complicated object.

```
<input type="checkbox" {{bindAttr checked="state"}}  {{action "flipMyCheck"}} />
```

I am hoping stack overflow can help before I just go old school jQuery.each() on it.

Comment: I ended up just using the value as it was and the unless helper later on in the handlebar.  Thanks anyway.

Comment: Can you post the code as an answer please ?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understand well your question.
Does this solve your problem ?

http://jsfiddle.net/Sly7/JDRFW/

Comment: Sorry no.  The issue is with doing that inside of a built in view like this -> {{view Ember.Checkbox checkedBinding="state"}}  I want to keep the data bound so I don't have to recreate the object over and over.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I definitely don't understand what you're looking for :(. I'll remove my answer when someone will post a correct one.